# Notify View of change object field

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvp, mschart

I use MVP pattern in my WinForms app. I've problem with implementation Real-Time data drawing Chart (MSChart).
I've some algorithm and presenter class:

```
public class Algorithm
{
     private double parameter1;
     public void Execute()
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            ...
            if (i % 10 == 0)
            {
                parameter1 = parameter1 * 0.95;
            }
            ...
     }
}

public class MainWindowPresenter
{    
     public void RunAlgorithm()
     {  
         Algorithm alg = new Algorithm();
         alg.Execute();  
     }        
}
```

I execute this algorithm in Presenter class. I want to notify View of change parameter1 and pass this change to chart (MSChart) and of course draw in Chart. This is my Form class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form, IMainWindowView
{
    private MainWindowPresenter presenter;
    ...
    private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => presenter.RunAlgorithm());                                      
    }
}
```

Drawing in Real-Time is no problem - I use `Task`, but how to notify View and Form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me just exactly what you are trying to achieve from your example code, but based on the information provided, something alongs the lines of the following should work:

- Change `Algorithm` to expose its `parameter1` value (e.g. by making it a public property).
- Your current design has one `Algorithm` instance per invocation of `RunAlgorithm` and thus possibly multiple `parameter1` values simultaneously, which seems unintended. Make `alg` a member of the `MainWindowPresenter` class so that you have one instance that is no longer scoped to the `RunAlgorithm` method. Add appropriate [locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) to prevent concurrency issues.
- Add [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to the `Algorithm` and `MainWindowPresenter` classes to notify observers (the form/view) of changes to parameter1. The `MainWindowPresenter` can forward the events fired by the `Algorithm` class. Note that these events will run on the thread that your `Task` is running on. In order to update controls in event handlers attached to these events you will then typically have to [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the UI thread.